# Is there an app which can play youtube videos during locked screen?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, youtube, youtube-dl

I guess my headline covered my question well.

An alternative question; Can youtube-dl run on ARM-processors, and can i run it on mx4 ubuntu touch?

Comment: Please split the questions as they're unrelated and include basic information what steps you have taken so far.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube-dl is a python script, so you could install the terminal app and apt-get the required packages. Or we make a small crowd founding campaign.